# Any ways to delete app in app store connect COMPLETELY?

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I have uploaded my app archive on Xcode with bundleID : com.aa.b
and I've deleted this app and want to upload app with bundleID: com.a.b

So in my App Store connect status,

app with bundleID:com.aa.b is in removed apps section.

app with bundleID:com.a.b is in my apps section.

I'm now trying to upload the archive of the app with bundleID:com.a.b
but it keeps sending error message that bundle id doesn't match to com.aa.b, which I deleted.
Why is this connecting to deleted app's bundleID??
is there any way that I can delete this app COMPLETELY from deleted apps section??

Comment: You don't need to delete anything in AppStore Connect. Just make sure the app you are building and trying to upload has the correct bundle id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. Apps are only "connected" and identified through their `bundle IDs`. Please make sure that in Xcode you have changed the bundle ID of the app and all extensions to the correct new bundle ID.

[image]